# How Slow Is Casting Or Generic Lists?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, generics, casting

**Simple:** `List<float[]>` + `List<int[]>` **vs.** `List<object>` with casting for both ?
Which would provide better performance ? Is the difference **very** significant ?

---

I have a very performance dependent windows application written in C# (not real-time though). I'm using **lists of arrays** that can be `float[]` or `int[]`. So I'm thinking how do I use them best:

1. put them in multiple lists
2. put them in multiple generic lists: `List<float[]>` and `List<int[]>`
3. put them in one `List<object>` and cast arrays to object and back

**The question is how slow/fast is generic and casting ?**
Or how do I store my arrays efficiently ?

---

**ADD:** All arrays are subject of "heavy" calculation. Single `int` and `float` values are not casted between each other. They only influence each other while calculation is done. float provides enough accuracy for my calculations, no double needed. (*Array size is up to 600. But that can change.*)

Comment: How about measure on yourself?

Comment: There is no casting when you use generics - they're a coding construct (probably not the best way to phrase it), but when the code is compiled the compiler will use the correct type in the emitted code.

Comment: How about converting them all to lists of `double`s? A double can store every possible value of a float or int, that way you avoid any casting at all.

Comment: Definitely not option 3 - there's no reason to do that kind of casting now that generics are part of the framework (since 2.0).  I think Alex has a good suggestion.  Another thing to consider is how much data are you dealing with? Are you doing any calculations with the data, and are there any *implicit* conversions in those calculations (like int / float)?  Things like that.

Comment: Do you experience any sort of performance hit? Premature optimization is the root of all evil, you know :)
The only way to know it is indeed profiling your data. Visual Studio 2012 has nice profiling capabilities. Even if your float[] or int[] constructs are terribly slow, without profiling you don't know if it is the slowest part of your application at all

Comment: @Tim I added some info in question. Please review. Why not the 3rd ? It was actually my favorite because I have to deal with only 1 list

Comment: The third alternative use boxing/unboxing... What exactly are you doing/how are you using lists or arrays?

Comment: @mini-me - What JeffRSon said primarily.  Boxing/Unboxing *will* be a performance hit.  You won't see any performance hits by using multiple generic lists, but you very well might (depending on how many calculations and in what timespan) if you go with option 3, even if it seems easier from a development point of view.  If you want to use option 3, you might as well use `ArrayList` :)

Comment: Casting can be slow up to 6 points.

Comment: @mini-me - can you provide a code sample of some of the calculations (sanitized if need be)?  It's difficult (for me at least) to visualize why you're concerned.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - 6 points?  points of what?

Comment: @Tim thats the answer on question *How slow is casting*. I think it's about 6 points of slowness

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - I got that it was an answer to how slow is casting :)  I was asking what is a point (I gather it's a measurement of some sort).

Comment: @Samuel: *"The conventional wisdom [..] calls for ignoring efficiency in the small; but I believe this is simply an overreaction to the abuses they see"* - same paper, interesting read: http://pplab.snu.ac.kr/courses/adv_pl05/papers/p261-knuth.pdf

Answer (score 2):

[Know What Things Cost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx) lists typical times of various managed operations. If you interpret them as *relative* and take them with a grain of salt, they are relatively stabel across processor generations.

But beware: I haven't yet understood why it lists double add as slower than float add. The underlying intructions are the same (or were last I checked, IIRC) - this might be memory effects, or something particular to managed code.

**Make sure float has enough accuracy.** Mul/div is fine, but repeated add/sub accuraccy loss accumulates quickly. There's no use for fast, wrong results - especially if they are not *obviously wrong*.

Generally I would default to double and use float only if I can make sure accuracy is enough and I have tangible evidence that I will run into memory access issues (such as inner loop exceeding typical L1/L2 cache sizes, or a performance measurement).

`List<float[]>` vs. multiple lists should have no tangible difference, provided the arrays aren't very small, and you are not resizing frequently.

Non-generic list is way out.

Comment: No list resizing is done. But did I understand you right you say option 2 better than option 3 ?

Comment: @mini-me: yes, using a list of objects is a bad idea. The value has to be boxed, abnd you introduce another level of redirection for each value. (Some of that might be optimized away under circumstances, but it remains a problem in general).

Comment: @peterchen `float[]` to `object` needs no boxing.

Comment: @tia: but float to object does, that's why storing *floats* in a list{object} is problematic. Now, you could also store float[] in a list{object} - I'd wonder why you would want to do that, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do `bluh[i] as TheTypeINeed`, and not really worry about it. Casting the entire list seems silly.

**I would also note the following:**

- Is there a reason why you are going through int/float (EDIT)cast all the time?
- Is C# the language you really want for such a performance demanding application?

I feel that there are other, more fundamental problems going on here at an architectural level.

Comment: There is no `int` <-> `float`! Only put/take out arrays of a List.